# Expected Specifier qualifier list error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hey guys, I know this problem caused due to the absent of importing header

But in my case, I've included the header but I still got the error?! What happens?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "WikitudeARCustomMenuButtonDelegate.h"
#import "DetailedARViewController.h"

@interface CustomMenuButtonDelegateImpl1 : NSObject <WikitudeARCustomMenuButtonDelegate> 
{
    DetailedARViewController *ARViewController;

}


@end
```

Comment: What are the contents of WikitudeARCustomMenuButtonDelegate.h and DetailedARViewController.h?

Comment: WikitudeARCustomMenuButtonDelegate.h is a protocol.

Comment: DetailedARViewController.h is my own class.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that "DetailedARViewController.h" really does define `DetailedARViewController`; in particular, check for subtle errors like misspellings or a declaration accidentally commented out.